# Yii - Belongs_To was working, now throws error

Tags: php, orm, yii

I have a User and Account model.  The relationship is User belongs to Account, Account has many Users.

Here is the model code for both:

**User Model**:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'account' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Account', 'account_id'),
    );
}
```

**Account Model**:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'users' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'User', 'account_id'),
                    'userCount'=>array(self::STAT,'User','account_id'),
            );
}
```

I have this code in my **UserIdentity.php** for logging in which WAS working just fine:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    $user=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('username'=>$this->username));
    if($user===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else{
                if($user->password!==$user->encrypt($this->password))
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
                else{
                    $this->_id=$user->id;
                    if($user->last_login_time==null)
                        $lastLogin=time();
                    else
                        $lastLogin=strtotime($user->last_login_time);
                    $this->setState('lastLoginTime', $lastLogin);
                    $this->setState('account',array('id'=>$user->account->id,'name'=>$user->account->name,));
                    $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
                }
            }
    return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

It started giving an error when I added another user to the account:

**PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object**.

The error points to

`$this->setState('account',array('id'=>$user->account->id,'name'=>$user->account->name,));`

When broken up into multiple lines:

`'id'=>$user->account->id,` is where the error lies.

To fix this, I simply changed it to this:

```
$account=Account::model()->findByPk($user->account_id);
$this->setState('account',array('id'=>$account->id,'name'=>$account->name,));
```

So the relationship worked just fine when I had a single user, but when I had 2 users, the relationship fails.  I can continue using Yii as above, but I did like the simplicity of accessing the object directly.  Did I not set up the relationships correctly?  Why is this not working now with 2 users in one account?

**EDIT:**

`var_dump($user)` - http://pastebin.com/TEyrFnme

Also interesting is that I can access the user from the account using: `$users=$account->users;` and access all the `$user[0]` attributes just fine.  So in reverse, the relationship seems to be working, just going forward seems to have difficulty.

Comment: Please split that single line with the error over mutliple lines so it is more clear which variable is used as an object but it is not one. You should also `var_dump` the error candidates so you can find out which one it is directly.

Comment: Okay, then `var_dump($user);` to find out *what* it is. I quickly scanned the code and all I can guess it is *not* NULL and *not* an object ;)

Comment: @hakre Updated.  Posted at http://pastebin.com/TEyrFnme.  Everything *looks* correct.  Lines 663 is where the relationship is stated.

Comment: Shrug, that is a lot of output :/ - doesn't that have better debugging tools? Anyway, my fault, try `var_dump($user->account);` as well. I bet that is more interesting.

Comment: Can you delete the second user and verify that it returns to working correctly? I've found that many times things that _should_ work right are caused by things other than what I expect, so it will help to verify that the 2nd user is in fact causing the problem. As you say, everything _looks_ correct.

Comment: Only 1 account, only 1 user, still throwing the error.  I have ran unit tests, still giving an error.

Comment: Have you declared `public $account;` in your User model? You shouldn't, but if you did, that would explain the error; as Yii will first try to use actual attributes, before looking at relations.

Comment: @WillemRenzema, post that as your answer and I will mark it as correct.  I have both models extending a class that in turn extends CActiveRecord.  In my parent class, I do have `public $account;`.  Deleted and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't declare a variable in your model with the same name as a relation.

```
public $account;
```

will prevent the model from looking for the `account` relation, as Yii will first look for (and use) actual attributes before checking for relations of the same name.